# Spring boot factoryBean threw exception on object creation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8

the java code below "should execute" the select on a sql database via spring boot to do it I use the repository below, but when I run the code I have the following error, how can I fix it and what is it due to?

**Error:**

```
Error creating bean with name 'rapportoRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.reportserver.report.repository.RapportoRepository.findbycantiere(int)!
```

**RapportoRepository.java:**

```
public interface RapportoRepository extends JpaRepository<Rapporto, Integer> {

    //Permette il caricamento dei rapportini presenti in un cantiere
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Rapporto where IdCantiere=:IdCantiere")
    List<Rapporto> findbycantiere(@Param("IdCantiere") int IdCantiere);
}
```

**ReportService.java**

```
@Description(value = "Report Cantieri")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/report")
public class ReportResource {
 @PostMapping(value = "/stampa/rapportini")
    public @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity<Object> stamparapportini(@Valid @RequestBody Cantiere cantierereport) throws JSONException {
        System.out.println("\n Chiamata a servizio rest stampa rapportini");
        List<Rapporto> listlp= rapportoRepository.findbycantiere(cantierereport.getIdCantiere());
        List<JSONObject> entities = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
        for (Rapporto rp : listlp) {
            JSONObject entity = new JSONObject();
            entity.put("IdRapporto", rp.getId());
            entity.put("Immagine", rp.getImmagine());
            entities.add(entity);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(entities, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Comment: Without your entity this is impossible to answer.

Comment: If spring-boot version is 2 you need to update, `@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "your sql_query")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It expect `HQL`, not `SQL` in that tag.

Try change to

```
@Query("FROM Rapporto where IdCantiere=:IdCantiere").
List<Rapporto> findbycantiere(@Param("IdCantiere") int IdCantiere);
```